# If/else Javascript statement not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using ajax to query a database and have json_encoded the results. Below is an example of one of the items. Comparing the `bid` and `user_points`, I either show a "not enough points" or "buy now" button.

```
[
    {
        "id": "205",
        "item_id": "727",
        "winner_id": "62",
        "bid": "153",
        "status": "1",
        "date": "2015-09-05 05:53:12",
        "exp_date": "2015-09-07 05:53:12",
        "user_id": "296",
        "item_title": "neptun",
        "stime": 84178,
        "time_left": "0 d : 23 h : 22 m",
        "user_points": "1222",
        "user_thumb": "images\/ppic\/15x\/296.jpg?x=timestamp"
    }
]
```

The Javascript which is used to append each element inside `#pending-wins`. The problem is with the `data[i].user_points < data[i].bid`. Using the above example, it should display the "buy now" button, instead the "not enough points" button is displayed. Any idea why?

```
$.each(data, function(i)
            {
                $("#pending-wins").append(
                    '<div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">\
                        <div class="thumbnail">\
                            <a href="item?id='+data[i].item_id+'"><img src="images/355x/'+data[i].item_id+'-1.jpg" alt="" /></a>\
                            <h3>'+data[i].item_title+'</h3>\
                            <div class="caption">\
                                <ul class="list-group">\
                                    <li class="list-group-item">\
                                        <span class="badge">'+data[i].bid+'</span>\
                                        Cost\
                                    </li>\
                                    <li class="list-group-item">\
                                        <span class="badge user-badge"><img src="'+data[i].user_thumb+'" alt="" /></span>\
                                        Seller\
                                    </li>\
                                    <li class="list-group-item">\
                                        <span class="badge">'+data[i].time_left+'</span>\
                                        Time left:\
                                    </li>'
                                    +(data[i].user_points < data[i].bid ?
                                        '<li class="list-group-item">\
                                            <span class="badge background-none"><a href="points"><button>Click here</button></a></badge></span>\
                                            Not enough points for this item.\
                                        </li>'
                                    :

                                        (data[i].stime <= 0 ?
                                            ''
                                        :
                                            '<li class="list-group-item center"><button id="claim-'+data[i].item_id+'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm claim">Claim Win</button></li>'
                                        )
                                    )+
                                '</ul>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>'
                );
            });
```

Comment: I don't see an if/else statement anywhere.

Comment: `"1222" < "153"` returns true. Strings are compared differently from integers.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response both `user_points` and `bid` are in string please converrt it into integer and pass it to the condition.

```
if(parseInt(data[i].user_points) < parseInt(data[i].bid))
```

Comment: Convert it where? Cast it as int in the php file before I encode it? Or in javascript?

Comment: @ciprian: In JS, "11" > "100", but 11 < 100.  JavaScript implicitly converts types, so you can either change it in the JSON (by not using quotes around the numbers) or typecast it to a number in JS.

Comment: That was it. Thank you. I thought that by setting the database column as `INT` was enough. And I missed the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is returning the `user_points` and `bid` as strings, and you want them to return as numbers. You should change your PHP to send the data differently.

Although, if you can't change the PHP, you can change your Javascript to convert them:

```js
var data =[
    {
        "id": "205",
        "item_id": "727",
        "winner_id": "62",
        "bid": "153",
        "status": "1",
        "date": "2015-09-05 05:53:12",
        "exp_date": "2015-09-07 05:53:12",
        "user_id": "296",
        "item_title": "neptun",
        "stime": 84178,
        "time_left": "0 d : 23 h : 22 m",
        "user_points": "1222",
        "user_thumb": "images\/ppic\/15x\/296.jpg?x=timestamp"
    }
];

$.each(data, function(i)
            {
                $("#pending-wins").append(
                    '<div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">\
                        <div class="thumbnail">\
                            <a href="item?id='+data[i].item_id+'"><img src="images/355x/'+data[i].item_id+'-1.jpg" alt="" /></a>\
                            <h3>'+data[i].item_title+'</h3>\
                            <div class="caption">\
                                <ul class="list-group">\
                                    <li class="list-group-item">\
                                        <span class="badge">'+data[i].bid+'</span>\
                                        Cost\
                                    </li>\
                                    <li class="list-group-item">\
                                        <span class="badge user-badge"><img src="'+data[i].user_thumb+'" alt="" /></span>\
                                        Seller\
                                    </li>\
                                    <li class="list-group-item">\
                                        <span class="badge">'+data[i].time_left+'</span>\
                                        Time left:\
                                    </li>'
                                    +(Number(data[i].user_points) < Number(data[i].bid) ?
                                        '<li class="list-group-item">\
                                            <span class="badge background-none"><a href="points"><button>Click here</button></a></badge></span>\
                                            Not enough points for this item.\
                                        </li>'
                                    :

                                        (data[i].stime <= 0 ?
                                            ''
                                        :
                                            '<li class="list-group-item center"><button id="claim-'+data[i].item_id+'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm claim">Claim Win</button></li>'
                                        )
                                    )+
                                '</ul>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>'
                );
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pending-wins"></div>
```

Short code:

```
Number(data[i].user_points) < Number(data[i].bid)
```